# Google Chrome Frame: Says it's installed, but it is actually not

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I'm installing Google Chrome Frame from this page (it offers you installation if you go there with IE) http://www.zgtechnologies.com/chrome/index.php
It says that the installation is completed, but there is no such plugin in my Add-ons menu of IE. Even after restart. I tried to use offline installer, tried to uninstall and install it again - no effect!
How to fix this? I need it for tests and now I have to use my another computer!
I use OS Win7 x64

Comment: I am also having this problem. Did you ever get an actual answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Google Chrome Frame from the official page: http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/

Alternatively, you can use [Google Chrome Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable).